# ADF - Web activity - 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing number: \". Path 'filesRead', line 3, position 53.'."}}

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

The purpose of the pipeline is to transfer csv files from one ADLS Gen2 container to another and to check dataRead-dataWritten as well as filesRead-filesWritten and to send the output as an email notification. The files transfer is successful as well as the verification but the web activity gives me an error : 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing number: ". Path 'filesRead', line 3, position 53.'."}}

[image: pipeline]

[image: web activity body]

Thank you in advance for your help,
BR

Comment: Are you sure the expression is correct? I think you might have not given double quotes correctly.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer, this was the problem! Now it works but have another problem. I don't receive any dataRead or dataWritten information in the email. It is like dataRead: , dataWritten: , and no values. FilesRead and FilesWritten is ok.

Comment: Check what values are getting stored in the variables used inside `dataRead` and `dataWritten` variables. Also, please edit the question to add details about the dynamic content used in those activities

Comment: Thank you for your answers. 
The problem was I hadn't followed the 'Set variable' and 'Variables' sequence. If the activities order is like dataRead -> dataWritten -> filesRead -> filesWritten, the pipeline 'variables' must be in the same order.